# Stripping extra newlines in Saxon

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon

I use Altova XMLSpy and Saxon. Saxon adds a lot of tabs and Newlines in the result file. So I added the templates (found here on stackoverflow):

```
<xsl:template match="*/text()[normalize-space()]">
   <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/text()[not(normalize-space())]" />
```

to the stylesheet, which neatly removed all extra white space. However, it also removed the space before and after the <i>....</i>  and <q>....</q> inside a <p>:

```
<p>this is <i>italic</i> text</p>
```

So both Altova and Saxon gave me:

```
<p>this is<i>italic</i>text</p>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I am not aware of Saxon adding tabs and new lines. Please post minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT and wanted and produced output so that we can understand where the white space comes from. We need to know the output method and the setting of the `indent` attribute on `xsl:output`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The indent was set to YES and when I set it to NO, Altova and Saxon do NOT add tabs and NLs. They also do not delete the mentioned space before and after the i/q tags. However, the output is not indented either, and so, is hardly readable. Seems to me, Saxon changes 0D/0A combinations to 0A with a lot of spaces.

Comment: Both XML parsing and XSLT serialization follow the rules in the relevant specifications, for instance http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-line-ends mandates that line endings are normalized by the XML parser. As I said, post minimal but complete samples allowing us to understand and reproduce the problem, then we can hopefully tell how to fix it. If the input is indented and you copy stuff through then I am sure that with Saxon the output is also indented, unless of course you remove pure white space text nodes with templates like `<xsl:template match="*/text()[not(normalize-space())]" />`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the xsl:output element to control indentation of the output.  Use xsl:strip-space and xsl:preserve-space to control whitespace handling of your input.

Use templates like the two you show only as a last resort.  Here, the first template is the one causing the loss of whitepace adjacent to your `i` elements, because the processors are doing what you told them to do, instead of what you meant to tell them to do.